# Calculate the total value of a group while keep information from the other column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I have a data frame as the following structure.

```
# Create example data
ex_df <- data.frame(
  Date = as.Date(c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-03",
                   "2000-01-04", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-05",
                   "2000-01-05")),
  Value = c(1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 3, 1),
  Label = c("A", "B", "A", "A", 
            "B", "A", "A", "A", "B"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ex_df
#         Date Value Label
# 1 2000-01-01     1     A
# 2 2000-01-02     3     B
# 3 2000-01-03     1     A
# 4 2000-01-03     2     A
# 5 2000-01-04     5     B
# 6 2000-01-04     2     A
# 7 2000-01-05     1     A
# 8 2000-01-05     3     A
# 9 2000-01-05     1     B
```

I would like to calculate the total `Value` of each `Date`, while keeping the information in the `Label` column. The desired output would be the following.

```
#        Date Value Label
#1 2000-01-01     1     A
#2 2000-01-02     3     B
#3 2000-01-03     3     A
#4 2000-01-04     7     B
#5 2000-01-05     5     B
```

In this data frame, I want `Label` to be `A` or `B` if all the rows from the same `Date` have the same label, such as the case in `2000-01-03`. However, if rows from the same `Date` have different labels, I want `Label` to be `B`, such as the case in `2000-01-04` and `2000-01-05`.

I know I can calculate the group total value using the `dplyr` package as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
ex_df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(Value = sum(Value))
```

But how can I keep the information in the `Label` column? I would welcome solutions not only using `dplyr`, but also `data.table`, base R, or other packages.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `B` is in *Label* for each group, if yes, return `B` in the summary else return `A`:

```
library(dplyr)
ex_df %>% group_by(Date) %>% 
    summarise(Value = sum(Value), Label = if("B" %in% Label) "B" else "A")

# A tibble: 5 × 3
#        Date Value Label
#      <date> <dbl> <chr>
#1 2000-01-01     1     A
#2 2000-01-02     3     B
#3 2000-01-03     3     A
#4 2000-01-04     7     B
#5 2000-01-05     5     B
```

Comment: For this specific case, there's `Label = max(Label)`. It could work more generally (maybe) so long as Label is a suitably ordered factor. (Oh, just saw P showed the first option in an answer.)

Comment: @Frank Agree `max` is a nice and concise option here.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do that is to use `max`  on Label

```
ex_df %>%
 group_by(Date) %>%
 summarise(Value = sum(Value),label=max(Label))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
        Date Value label
      <date> <dbl> <chr>
1 2000-01-01     1     A
2 2000-01-02     3     B
3 2000-01-03     3     A
4 2000-01-04     7     B
5 2000-01-05     5     B
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
# Create example data
ex_df <- data.table(
  Date = as.Date(c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-03",
                   "2000-01-04", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-05",
                   "2000-01-05")),
  Value = c(1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 3, 1),
  Label = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
foo <- function(x) { u <- unique(x); ifelse(length(u)==1, u, "B") }
ex_df[, .(Value=sum(Value), Label=foo(Label)), by=Date]
#          Date Value Label
# 1: 2000-01-01     1     A
# 2: 2000-01-02     3     B
# 3: 2000-01-03     3     A
# 4: 2000-01-04     7     B
# 5: 2000-01-05     5     B
```

a shorter variant:

```
ex_df[, .(Value=sum(Value), Label=max(Label)), by=Date]
```

Comment: Thank you. The short variant only takes one line of code, wonderful!